# Can you use a dynamic content block from content builder in Mobile Connect?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect

Is it possible to use a dynamic content block created in content builder in a Mobile Connect SMS? For example the SMS content would read "Hi this is a fancy message here is your coupon %%=ContentBlockbyId("67053")=%%. Thanks!".

The dynamic content is based on the same Data Extension as will be used to send the SMS.

Comment: Did you figure out whether this was possible?

Comment: Nope, haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

[No](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/contentblockbyid.htm). Though you *may* be able to use [Code Snippets](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_create_code_snippet.htm&type=5) for MobileConnect.

> These functions support email messages only. For text-only parts of the email, such as From Address, From Name, or Subject Line, reference the code snippet block.

Comment: You can use the ContentBlockbyId function in a SMS message but need to be sure that you call only Code Snippets with AMPscript and/or text in them. The other content block types utilize HTML which will not render in a SMS message.